# Objective-C ARC: passing an object as argument

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, automatic-ref-counting

Suppose there is method:

```
     - (void)doSomething:(id)thing
     {
          uintptr_t retainCount =  _objc_rootRetainCount(thing);
          //do some thing
     }
```

It's not very clear whether compiler will retain the passing object.

I test in xcode5, it seems compiler will retain the passing object in this case, the same as `(id __strong)`. But it also retain it when I use `(id __weak)`, this is strange.If I use `__autoreleasing` or `__unsafe_unretained`, passing object is not retained, but it should be retained when using `__autoreleasing`.

It's totoally different from using these ownership qualifers with local variable or instance variable, what's the expected behavior and why. I cann't find anything about this from Apple's document.

I test by using:

```
  extern uintptr_t  _objc_rootRetainCount(id obj);
```

I use it in the method, and before call the method.

Comment: please correct your typos. there is no "compier" or "`__autorelsing`"

Comment: how do you know it is retaining or not? can you post your testing code?

Comment: http://whentouseretaincount.com

Comment: An object passed as a parameter is simply passed.  So long as the method is invoked, whatever "hold" the calling method has on the object remains.  Nothing more needs to be done, unless the called method wants to cache the pointer somewhere (in which case the called method is responsible to use the proper protocols).

Comment: And you know, of course, that with ARC the retain count is unreliable as an indication of whether the object is actually retained.

Comment: I got a major bingo on LMGTFY with ["clang documentation method parameter retained"](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#consumed-parameters) `(ns_consumed)` -- you learn something new every day. "When passing such an argument, ARC retains the argument prior to making the call."

Comment: Behavior will change across compiler versions and optimization levels.